# Why do I get "Wireless unavailable"?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, dell, inspiron

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04. on my Dell Inspirion Mini 1018. After doing one of regular updates, my wifi stopped working, and it gives me message `Wireless is disabled by hardware switch`.

How can I enable it? I tried opening network connections, but there I find: `Wireless Unavailable. Hardware Address 1C:65:9D:68:9E:6B`

Then I tried System testing, it gives me a message:

```
# For some Atheros 5K RF MACs, the madwifi driver loads buts fails to
# correctly initialize the hardware, leaving it in a state from
# which ath5k cannot recover. To prevent this condition, stop
# madwifi from loading by default. Use Jockey to select one driver
# or the other. (Ubuntu: #315056, #323830)
  blacklist ath_pci"
```

This what I get after nm-tool :

```
Type: 802.11 WiFi
Driver: rtl8192ce
State: unavailable
Default: no
HW Address: 1C:65:9D:68:9E:6B

Capabilities:
Wireless Properties
WEP Encryption: yes
WPA Encryption: yes
WPA2 Encryption: yes

Wireless Access Points
```

Next command I used `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network DISABLED
description: Wireless interface
product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
logical name: wlan0
version: 01
serial: 1c:65:9d:68:9e:6b
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.2.0-37-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0100000-f0103fff
```

As I am new on Ubuntu, I asked on Newbees forum, and here is what i did so far

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2116769

One who was guiding me has no idea what to try next.

Comment: this is rough. In the thread they suggest to reset BIOS to default settings. Did you do that? If not, restart your computer and hold Ctrl-F11 immediately after startup.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I'm guessing this has nothing to do with Ubuntu: you have to press some keyboard key to activate the card (for example, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> keys)